# Center React Navigation header on Android title

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I am using React Navigation and on IOS the headers are centered as intended but on Android the buttons which should be on the left and the title are all justified to the left. Does anyone know how to fix this? Here is the code:

```
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name = "Home" component={HomeScreen}

        options={{


            headerLeft: () => (
              <Button
                onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
                title="Open Menu"
                color="blue"


                />
              ),
            }}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

Thank you

Also I found similar questions but they seemed to be out of date because things like textalign did not work.

Answer (score 0):

React Navigation is updated so frequently, that you can not catch up with it.

If you are on version 5.x or above, you can try something like below:

```
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{headerTitleAlign: 'center'}}>
  ...
</Stack.Navigator>
```